# How to program daily downscale and upscape of Google Kubernetes Engine nodes and pods based on current time

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that runs pods of several environments (dev, pre, pro). In order to reduce costs I would like to stop some nodes during the night, and keep only the necessary to run production pods. Then in the morning I want to upscale the nodes and start the dev/pre pods.

**Peak Hours**

```
Node1 -> ProdPod1 DevPod1
Node2 -> ProdPod2 PrePod1
  .
  .
NodeN -> DevPod2 ProdPod3
```

**Valley Hours**

```
Node1 -> ProdPod1 ProdPod2 ProdPod3
```

Does GKE provide some way of programming this downscaling/upscaling of nodes and pods? If not how could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, if you're arbitrarily killing *nodes*, while Kubernetes was requested to run (and is running) a specific workload utilizing specific resources, how do you expect it to know what pods to kill?
(You can address this with pod priorities, but I wouldn't recommend that).

What you want to look at is the [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).
Just make sure to kill the dev/test workloads at night, and the auto-scaler will take care of the rest.
I'd get into more detail, but this sounds extremely like a [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), so I don't recommend taking the path you're going to take unless the amount of money you'll be saving is significant, i.e., worth more than your time ;-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that if you want to save money, and if your dev pods can tolerate some downtime, you'd want to look at using [preemptible or spot instances](https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/0).  Some good insights [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-preemptible-vms-to-cut-kubernetes-engine-bills-in-half-de2481b8e814)

Comment: I was thinking of something like being able to program some kind of scheduled task that would set the replica count of dev/pre k8s deployments to 0 and rely on the gke cluster autoscaling (downscaling) to kill unneeded nodes. Any hint of how such a scheduled task could be programmed?